# what is the quickest way to drop zeros from a series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm encountered this problem several times and always doing something different each time.  What do others do?

Consider the series `s`

```
s = pd.Series([1, 0, 2], list('abc'), name='s')
```

What is the quickest way to to produce

```
a    1
c    2
Name: s, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean slicing is probably the easiest way:

```
In [1]: s = pd.Series([1, 0, 2], list('abc'), name='s')

In [2]: s[s != 0]
Out[2]:
a    1
c    2
Name: s, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things I've done

***method 1***
`numpy`

```
z = np.nonzero(s.values)
pd.Series(s.values[z], s.index.values[z], name=s.name)
```

***method 2***
`to_frame` + `query`

```
s.to_frame().query('s != 0').squeeze()
```

***method 3***
`replace` + `dropna`

```
s.replace(0, np.nan).dropna().astype(s.dtype)
```

---

All yield

```
a    1
c    2
Name: s, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly there are many ways to get the same result. I think boolean indexing is the simplest way to do it but I would test the speed performance of different methods also. Here it goes:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 0, 2], list('abc'), name='s')
```

#### Method 1

```
%%timeit
z = np.nonzero(s.values)
pd.Series(s.values[z], s.index.values[z], name=s.name)

## -- End pasted text --
The slowest run took 5.23 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
10000 loops, best of 3: 83.9 µs per loop
```

#### Method 2

```
%%timeit
s.to_frame().query('s != 0').squeeze()

## -- End pasted text --
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.86 ms per loop
```

#### Method 3

```
%%timeit
s.replace(0, np.nan).dropna().astype(s.dtype)

## -- End pasted text --
1000 loops, best of 3: 295 µs per loop
```

#### Method 4

```
%%timeit
s[s != 0]

## -- End pasted text --
10000 loops, best of 3: 188 µs per loop
```

To my surprise Method 1 seems to be the fastest and Method 4 is a close second. Perhaps numpy operations are much faster than pandas and that could be the reason.